# How to free up space after kernel compile fail - where are the extraneous stuff

Tags: kernel, compiling, macintosh, source

I need custom patch my linux kernel so it can access the MacBook Pro (2018/2019) SSD for Ubuntu installation. Luckily, someone made a patch that seems to work. I have a second computer with a 1TB drive and there was several hundred GB's (maybe 500GB?). So I thought I would go ahead and compile from source (kernel 5.2). Well, I guess I should have cleaned my config file, because the kernal compile returned error that there was not enough disk space to proceed. Whaaaa?

Anyway, I'm having difficulty finding out where all the space went. When the compile fails, where are the files? What should I delete from the failed compile to try again with a much better config? I guess I could just rewipe the partition and reinstall linux again, but I'd like to avoid that if the fix is relatively easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you can do:

```
make clean
```

to clean up most artifacts generated by the build.

Comment: Oh right! I guess I've associated "make clean" as a post compile task. Totally off my radar.